# PDO, mysql, transactions and table locking

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, locking, pdo

For fun I am replacing the mysqli extension in my app with PDO.

Once in awhile I need to use transactions + table locking.

In these situations, according to the mysql manual, the syntax needs to be a bit different.  Instead of calling START TRANSACTION, you do it like so...

```
SET autocommit=0;
LOCK TABLES t1 WRITE, t2 READ, ...;
... do something with tables t1 and t2 here ...
COMMIT;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables-and-transactions.html)

My question is, how does this interact with PDO::beginTransaction?  Can I use PDO::beginTransaction in this case?  Or should I manually send the sql "SET autocommit = 0; ... etc".

Thanks for the advice,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In MySQL, beginning a transaction is different than turning off autocommit, due to how LOCK/UNLOCK TABLES works.  In MySQL, LOCK TABLES commits any open transactions, but turning off autocommit isn't actually starting a transaction.  MySQL is funny that way.

In PDO, starting a transaction using [`beginTransaction`](http://php.net/pdo.begintransaction) doesn't actually start a new transaction, it just turns off autocommit.  In most databases, this is sane, but it can have side effects with MySQL's mentioned behavior.

You probably should not rely on this behavior and how it interacts with MySQL's quirks.  If you're going to deal with MySQL's behavior for table locking and DDL, you should avoid it.  If you want autocommit off, turn it off by hand.  If you want to open a transaction, open a transaction by hand.

You can freely mix the PDO API methods of working with transactions and SQL commands when not otherwise working with MySQL's oddities.

Comment: "Beginning a transaction is different than turning off autocommit" Not with PDO it isn't. When you call [PDO::beginTransaction()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php), it turns off auto commit.

Comment: Good point, I've updated my answer accordingly.  I eagerly await the day that MySQL gains sane DDL and lock behavior inside transactions...  Well, maybe not.  Made the switch to Postgres a while ago.

Comment: Could you please check this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47810114/php-pdo-mysql-and-how-does-it-really-deal-with-mysql-transactions I still can't understand the difference between using `PDO::beginTransaction()` with and without `$this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT,0);`. Could you please help? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 11):

When you call [PDO::beginTransaction()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php), it turns off auto commit.

So you can do:

```
$db->beginTransaction();
$db->exec('LOCK TABLES t1, t2, ...');
# do something with tables
$db->commit();
$db->exec('UNLOCK TABLES');
```

After a commit() or rollBack(), the database will be back in auto commit mode.

Comment: This has not been my experience (using mysql 5.6.27 with InnoDB tables), the 'LOCK TABLES' command basically commits the previously started transaction, and all subsequent commands are individually commited (i.e. no transaction behaviour)

Comment: Not all databases will allow transactions to operate on DDL statements: some will generate errors, whereas others (including MySQL) will automatically commit the transaction after the first DDL statement has been encountered.

Answer (score 7):

I have spent a huge amount of time running around this issue, and the PHP documentation in this area is vague at best. A few things I have found, running PHP 7 with a MySQL InnoDB table:

**PDO::beginTransaction doesn't just turn off autocommit**, having tested the answer provided by Olhovsky with code that fails, rollbacks do not work; there is no transactional behaviour. This means it can't be this simple.

**Beginning a transaction may be locking the used tables**... I eagerly await for someone to tell me I'm wrong with this, but here are the reasons it could be: [This comment](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php#90239), which shows a table being inaccessible when a transaction has started, without being locked. [This PHP documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php), that slips in on the end:

> ... while the transaction is active, you are guaranteed that no one else can make changes while you are in the middle of your work

To me this behaviour is quite smart, and also provides enough wiggle room for PDO to cope with every database, which is after all the aim. If this is what is going on though, its just massively under documented and should've been called something else to avoid confusion with a true database transaction, which doesn't imply locking.

Charles' answer I think is probably the best if you are after certainty with a workload that will require high concurrency; do it by hand using explicit queries to the database, then you can go by the database's documentation.

**Update**
I have had a production server up and running using the PDO transaction functions for a while now, recently using AWS's Aurora database (fully compatible with MySQL but built to automatically scale etc). I have proven these two points to myself:

- Transactions (purely the ability to commit all database changes together) work using PDO::beginTransaction(). In short, I know many scripts have failed half way through their database select/updates and data integrity has been maintained.
- Table locking isn't happening, I've had an index duplication error to prove this.

So, to further my conclusion, looks like the behaviour of these functions seems to change based on database engine (and possibly other factors). As far as I can tell both from experience and the documentation, there is no way to know programmatically what is going on... whoop...

Comment: "... there is no way to know programmatically what is going on... whoop..." - This is now my favorite quote on stack.